# code::blocks CPU spike

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks 8.02 in Ubuntu 9.10.  If I leave Code::Blocks open for several hours, I notice that it's consuming a LOT of CPU.  If I actually click on the application, the CPU usage immediately drops.  Is anyone else having this problem?  Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've noticed this issue before but then again I use C::B in win32. Have you tried the latest nightly builds to see if the same problem still happens?